# python dictionary, stored in mongodb, retrieved in ruby on rails

Tags: python, ruby, mongodb

I have a python script running a periodic process and then storing a number of dictionaries of lists of unknown size in mongodb.

e.g.,

`[0:{1, 2, 3}, 1: {8, 9, 10}, 2: {5, 12, 12}]`

I then try to retrieve these data from a ruby on rails (ror) app.

Is there any way to retrieve these dictionaries in ror in preformatted way (for example in a hash)?

Comment: Could you store the dictionaries as JSON objects?

Answer (score 2):

The best answer here is not to store the data as a Python dictionary, as that is a format you are unlikely to find an easy read solution for in Ruby. I'd be willing to bet there is a good JSON implementation in Ruby, and [there is one in Python](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) - so I'd say encode as JSON in Python, decode in Ruby.

Comment: Yes, Ruby [ships with JSON](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html).